# Failed to Install Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, debian, beagleboneblack, mysql-5.7

i try to install mysql server 5.7 in my beaglebone black with OS Debian Jessie, i following this instruction http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-setup . but when i using apt-get update, it always give me an error.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'mysql-apt-config/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

This error is make me insane, i try to using apt-get clean, deleting mysql.list but still give me that error.

Really appreciate if you can help me, thanks.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: There is already bug logged with MySql on 5.7 release, you can refer to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76174 
 and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this means that this repository doesn't provide ARMv7 hardfloat builds of packages. Probably only meant for i386 and AMD64 machines.

You could install mySQL 5.6 from [jessie-backports](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie-backports&keywords=mysql) if that version is enough for your needs. If you need 5.7 you'd either need to rebuild packages (very slow) or dist-upgrade to Debian SID (beware, can be unstable).